# AWS OpenSearch Index and Domain Limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm doing research on the capabilities of OpenSearch and I was having trouble finding certain information. Here is the information I had trouble finding or figuring out. Any help or answers to any of these would be greatly appreciated.

1. What is the maximum number of transactions per second (TPS) an OpenSearch Domain and Index can handle?
2. What is the maximum size of an individual record (row) in OpenSearch?
3. What is the maximum size of an individual feature (column) in OpenSearch?
4. What is the maximum number of columns in an OpenSearch Index (table)?
5. What is the maximum number of columns you can query at once in an OpenSearch Index?
6. Does AWS OpenSearch charge for read and write queries? How much?

Comment: Were you able to find out the answer to question #6?

Comment: [j.ian.le](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10882535/j-ian-le), the answer is no, AWS do not bill based on R/W volumes. What _might_ be significant is the standard AWS data transfer charges for the data transferred in and out of OpenSearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For question 2,3,4:**

Opensearch save data as a document (similar NoSql)

Maximum Document Size: 100KB

Maximum Indexing Payload Size: 10MB

**For question 5:**

Results Per Query: 10,000 results

**For question 1,2:**

Yes, AWS will charge a fee upon instance (which contains vCPU, RAM,..) per hour. Stronger instance you get larger money you will pay

Use the following formula to calculate the maximum active threads for search requests:

*int ((# of available_processors * 3) / 2) + 1*

Use the following formula to calculate maximum active threads for write requests:

*int (# of available_processors)*